# std::remove is not removing from std::vector

Tags: c++, std

Here is my issue:
In my GUI, there are several types of listeners. They are stored in `std::vector<WhateverListener*>`

In my GUI, I have a method called `removeListeners` and it looks like this:

```
void Widget::removeListeners( Widget* widget )
{
    removeFocusListener((FocusListener*)widget);
    removeMouseListener((MouseListener*)widget);
    removeKeyboardListener((KeyboardListener*)widget);
    removeWidgetListener((WidgetListener*)widget);
}
```

Basically, I do not think it should matter how I cast it; they are just pointers. I think `std::remove` simply compares pointers, therefore if I provide a widget* then it shouldn't affect anything (I think).

How the remove functions look is something like this:

```
void Widget::removeWidgetListener( 
                                    WidgetListener *listener )
{
    widgetListeners.erase(
        std::remove(widgetListeners.begin(),
        widgetListeners.end(), listener),
        widgetListeners.end());
}
```

So, in the Widget destructor, I iterate through the widget's children and call `removeListeners()`:

```
Widget::~Widget(void)
{

    for(std::vector<Widget*>::iterator it = getChildBegin();
        it != getChildEnd(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->removeListeners(this);
        (*it)->parentWidget = NULL;
        (*it)->_container = NULL;
    }

}
```

It does not work. After calling delete on a Widget which was listening to its children, the children still had listeners.

However, if I call the `remove` methods directly, and the widget inherits from the listener, it works:

```
Widget::~Widget(void)
{

    for(std::vector<Widget*>::iterator it = getChildBegin();
        it != getChildEnd(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->removeWidgetListener(this);
        (*it)->parentWidget = NULL;
        (*it)->_container = NULL;
    }

}
```

So why does one work and not the other? The only difference I spot is that in the first one I'm casting a Widget to that type. But I thought it would just compare pointers and if they were == it would remove it?

Comment: Casting tells the compiler "*I* know the type of this variable, even if you don't." You shouldn't cast a pointer to a type which it isn't really. Is every `Widget*` passed to `removeListeners()` simultaneously a focus, mouse, keyboard and widget listener?

Comment: Better amend the title to mention `erase`, as I and maybe others first thought this was just another question that didn't understand how `remove` works. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: Yup, I had typed _that_ answer before reading the post, and then deleted it in 5 seconds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your issue seems to be an incorrect design. The need to cast as you are doing implies that the function is in the wrong place. It's not clear from your post what the relationship between Widgets and the different types of Listener classes are.

You need to rethink where you are calling the removeListeners function from and instead of putting it in the base class destructor, you should put it in the destructor of the class that actually knows which type of listener it is (and only call the correct one).

It's hard to be more specific without getting some more detail on the relationships between your classes. In general, if you have to cast, you should ask yourself if there is a better way to accomplish what it is that's forcing you to cast.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you might be getting stung by object identity and virtual base classes in C++

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html

Basically, converting pointers to polymorphics bases, is not guaranteed to result in identical pointer values (when cast to (void*) e.g.).

It *should* work as long as you store the exact same pointer *type* as what you *cast it to* during removal, but I can't be sure without looking at more of your code/widget class hierarchy.

Comment: So I should dynamically cast before removal then

Comment: Yup, but only to the exact type that you insert them as. I personally think the casts are a smell, but you should definitely consider dynamic_cast<> for this type of scenario